# How to create variable for segue name?

Tags: ios, ios7

If I have several segues from one viewcontroller to another, is there some way to assign their identifiers into a variable so the variable can be referenced rather than a literal string, as shown below?

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@", segue.identifier);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"someSegueName"]){
    //push to view controller
    }
}
```

I'd like it so if the identifier name changes, it will update the variable assignment.

Comment: No. There is no way to do that. And if somehow (By Obj-C runtime of plugin) if you manage to get that it will not be useful as you want. And the reason for this is there can be many segue from one ViewController. So you will get array of identifier and you have to work with index. Now if you code for array and index you have to change your code when ever a new segue come or old segue deleted. So ultimately you have to change code thats why it is not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not excatly got it why are you trying to do it so ? You can try below logics if it suits you.

You can try with enum by giving enum values for the different segues as strings and using that strings for the identifier.

Can store in the Array and use accordingly

Another way would be by creating constants for the each and every identifier.

Comment: If the identifier name is changed, all of your suggestions require updating the identifier in two locations.  It would be best to grab the identifier name from where ever Xcode is storing it and assign that value to some global variable.

Comment: @4thSpace Using a segue name here is like saying, are you THAT segue (because this method is common for all the segues). If you don't use the name, how can you expect runtime to determine THAT is the segue? I don't think you can get the changes in segue in storyboard change the segue name in your code, if that is what you want. Of course, you could write an utility to update the segue name in storyboard that would then go to your class files and update it too. But that's another overkill.

Comment: Or, the utility could be something that you can run any time, which would look for segue elements (or it's container) in the storyboard file (XML) and update the segue names in your code...

Answer (score 0):

You could save it to a variable when that method is called the first time in this way: -

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@", segue.identifier);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"someSegueName"]){
        someVariable = seague; // This is my addition.
        //push to view controller
    }
}
```

But, I would recommend you to save the segue names in a constant string in your class so that you can use that repeatedly without making mistakes. This way, changing the segue name will also be easier later.

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%@", segue.identifier);
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:someVariable]){ //I've changed this line
        someVariable = seague;
        //push to view controller
    }
}
```